# PHP query dependent on the filled form

Tags: php, sql, forms

I am making a page to retrieve data from MySQL table. There are 6 fields with a drop-down menu, where 1 is required to select an option and other 5 are not required (optional).

```
Field1 (required)
Field2 (optional)
Field3 (optional)
Field4 (optional)
Field5 (optional)
Field6 (optional)
```

Now I want to run SQL to retrieve data based on the filled field. Let's consider below cases:

If only 2 fields are selected,
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = field1 AND column2 = field2`
field2 can be replaced with other fields too (total 5 combinations)

If only 3 fields are selected,
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = field1 AND column2 = field2 AND column3=field3"`
field2 and field3 can be field4, field5 and field6 too, total 10 possibilities

If 4 fields are selected, there are 6 possibilities.

So, how can I run just one query to select data from the table if any combination is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['field1']) && $_POST['field1']!=''){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column1 = '".$field1."'";
   if(isset($_POST['field2']) && $_POST['field2'] != ''){
        $sql .= " AND column2 = '".$_POST['field2']."'";
    }

     // and so on

     // execute your sql statement...
 }else{
  echo 'required field1 is empty';
 }
```